# Rails 6: How to disable Webpack and use Sprockets instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-sprockets

I'm migrating a Rails 5.2 app to 6.0 for ActionMailbox, ActionText, and multiple databases. However, I don't know webpack and would like to use Sprockets instead.

How do I properly remove webpack from Rails 6 and install Sprockets? `rails new app` installs webpack files right away. Is there a way to default to sprockets easily?

Rails (*Ruby*) was supposed to be **convention over configuration**, but Webpack (*Javascript*) cancels this by adding a lot of config and complexity.

Comment: `rails new —help` gives you lots of options during app creation.

Comment: I ended up going back to Rails 5.2.4 since the Rails 6 features weren't worth the cost (RAM + effort)

Comment: Did you ever manage to get actiontext to work without webpacker?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to skip adding webpacker gem when generating new rails application, use --skip-javascript (since Webpacker the default JavaScript compiler for Rails 6).

as noted from [this reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33079)

Answer (score 48):

I found [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/b0goct/webpacker_for_non_js_people/eih2930/) helpful, I will crosspost here:

Use option --skip-webpack-install when generating a new app

Change Gemfile, remove `webpacker`, add:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 4'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
```

Then

```
bundle update sass-rails sprockets # if you are updating 
bundle install # or simply install
```

If you are using sprockets 4, change `app/assets/config/manifest.js` to:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link application.js
//= link application.css
```

If you are using sprockets 3, add to `config/initializers/assets.rb`:

```
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.js )
```

Restore `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Change `javascript_pack_tag` to `javascript_include_tag` in `app/views/layout/application.html.erb`

Comment: Works for me (https://github.com/ecovillage/cabler/commit/c0329c77613faaf747004986e2df1eb5b5cb35b8)

Comment: One thing to note: if using the `--skip-keeps` option when generating the Rails app, it doesn't create the `app/assets/images` folder, which crashes Sprockets without mentioning why. Running ```touch app/assets/images/.keep``` fixes that. I wasted a few hours on that hurdle!

Comment: This doesn't work for me, since I have an `application.scss` file. Here is my manifest.js:   ```//= link_tree ../images
  //= link_directory ../javascripts .js
  //= link_directory ../stylesheets .scss
  //= link application.scss```