# Rails New 6.1 app unable to process any request besides default screen: Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, babeljs, ruby-on-rails-6.1

On a brand new rails `6.1.7.4` app, I'm getting the following error when making a request to any page besides the default "Rails::WelcomeController#index" screen:

> Webpacker::Manifest::MissingEntryError in Blogs#Index

[image: Error Message]

### Reproduction steps:

```
rails new rails_6-1_app
cd rails_6-1_app
rails g scaffold blog title
rails db:migrate
rails s
# Make request to http://localhost:3000/blogs/
```

### Environment:

- Ruby 2.7.4p191
- Rails 6.1.7.4
- node 16.20.2 (but node versions 18 and 20 were attempted as well)
- yarn 1.22.19
- macOS Ventura 13.5

### Webpacker:compile error

I notice that when I attempt `rails webpacker:compile` I get more information on what is going on:

```
Compiling...
Compilation failed:
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: Cannot find package '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods' imported from /<Path-TO-MY-APP>/rails_6-1_app/babel-virtual-resolve-base.js
```

It was suggested [via this rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48372) to modify two lines within the default, generated **babel.config.js** file:

```
// babel.config.js 
// replace this line 
// '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods',
// with this line
'@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods', 

// also replace this line
// '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object',
// with this line
'@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object',
```

However, making that change and then running `rails webpacker:compile` generates a new error:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:69:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/<Path-To-My-App>/rails_6-1_app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
```

Comment: You are most likely missing Node modules. You need to run `rails webpacker:install`. If that works then it's a duplicate question to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54113179/rails-webpackermanifestmissingentryerror-in-homeindex

Comment: @Casper unfortunately that did not resolve it for me.

Comment: There is currently an open issue that appears to be relevant. Unfortunately the proposed solution in that thread didn't work for me either: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48372

Comment: I *strongly* recommend migrating to https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer functions as a work around: I simply disabled webpacker and reverted back to using sprockets. You apparently don't have to use webpacker at all. I used [this SO post as a reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213868/rails-6-how-to-disable-webpack-and-use-sprockets-instead) to configure a new rails `6.1` app to use sprockets.

### Reproduction steps

First create the app but without webpacker:

```
rails new rails_6-1_app --skip-webpack-install
cd rails_6-1_app
rails g scaffold blog title
rails db:migrate
```

---

Within `Gemfile`, comment out `gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'` and then add the following gems:

```
# Gemfile
# comment out webpacker
# gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 4'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
```

---

Update **app/assets/config/manifest.js** so it looks like this:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link application.js
//= link application.css
```

---

Add the file **app/assets/javascripts/application.js** with this:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Within **app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**, replace `javascript_pack_tag` with `javascript_include_tag`.

---

Run `bundle install`

Now when I boot the server up with `rails s` and make a request to the app via `http://localhost:3000/blogs`, it works.

[image: blogs index screen]

Note that this was merely tested in development mode and not in production mode, and I did not test with any assets (images, additional css, bootstrap, custom javascript, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Same error is issued here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48372

**Description:**

This appears to be happening because webpacker generates a [`babel.config.js`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/1cec8408d9c30e458c9f83b0c50ef53a255a4352/lib/install/config/babel.config.js#L57-L60) that includes `plugin-proposal-private-methods`. However it does not add a dependency to `plugin-proposal-private-methods`. Instead, it depends on a package that depends on `plugin-proposal-private-methods`.

Recently that package was re-named to `plugin-transform-private-methods` [babel/babel#15614](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/15614) and probably it was released [babel/babel@389ecb0](https://github.com/babel/babel/commit/389ecb08ed502cd13671928c1ab9caccb72f0a6f).

So now when babel tries to execute it reads in the `babel.config.js` file, sees that it needs `plugin-proposal-private-methods`. Tries to load it, but that fails because `plugin-proposal-private-methods` is not installed (since it is no longer a dependency).

**Solution:**

You can replace the name in your `babel.config.js` from `proposal` to `transform`:

```js
// '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods',
'@babel/plugin-transform-private-methods', 

// '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object',
'@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object',

// etc.
```

Comment: This solution for me generates a new error when I run `rails webpacker:compile`: `Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported`.

Comment: Did you check it? https://stackoverflow.com/q/69692842/10608621